# RequestBody is not returning username - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, pom.xml

I'm making a POST request to authenticate the API that I'm implementing, but I have the following problem:

My username is not being returned:
[image]

however, my password is, and I'm not understanding why:

[image]

Below I will be sending my source code for better understanding...

**Class: AuthController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;
    
    @ApiOperation(value = "Authenticate a user by credentials") //Swagger endpoint description
    @PostMapping(value="/signin", produces = { "application/json", "application/xml", "application/x-yaml" }, consumes = {
            "application/json", "application/xml", "application/x-yaml" })
    public ResponseEntity singin(@RequestBody AccountCredentialsVO data) throws Exception {
        
        try {
            
            var username = data.getUserName();
            var password = data.getPassword();
            
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
            
            var user = repository.findByUserName(username);
            
            var token = "";
            
            if(user != null) {
                token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(username, user.getRoles());
            }else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username " + username + " not found!");
            }
            
            Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            
            model.put("username", username);
            model.put("token", token);
            return ok(model);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username/password supplied!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Class: AccountCredentialsVO.java**

```
public class AccountCredentialsVO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUserName() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.username = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(password, username);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AccountCredentialsVO other = (AccountCredentialsVO) obj;
        return Objects.equals(password, other.password) && Objects.equals(username, other.username);
    }

}
```

**The pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.andrefilipeos</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-with-springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Creating API RESTFul with Spring Boot 2.x</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- for Spring-boot Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for Tests Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dozermapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for XML support-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for YML or YAML support-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for HATEOAS Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for Swagger Support -->
        <!-- http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- it's format all API documentation organized -->
        <!-- http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for Security Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- for Tokens Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <!-- for Migration support $mvn flyway:migrate -->
                    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rest_with_springboot?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;useSSL=false</url>
                        <user>root</user>
                        <password>admin123</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>

</project>
```

My **POST** request:

**http://localhost:8080/auth/signin**

With XML (application/xml):

```
<AccountCredentialsVO>
    <username>leandro</username>
    <password>admin123</password>
</AccountCredentialsVO>
```

With JSON (application/json):

```
{
    "username":"leandro",
    "password":"admin123"
}
```

And unfortunately  with both requests I'm getting the same result of null username!

Comment: The getter and setter of your `AccountCredentialsVO` don't match the Java convention that Jackson (and probably other frameworks) works with. If your field name is `username` then their name should be `getUsername` / `setUsername` and not `getUserName`/`setUserName`.

Comment: I was the problem @BaptisteBeauvais